# wordpress auto generate pages from sub url of page

Tags: wordpress, url, output

Hoping someone can help. I don't want to create actual pages in the backend of wordpress but i want to know how i can make it so if anyone goes to a url: mydomain.com/page/sub-url.

Then i can grab that "sub-url" and output a page with content i generate via php.
If i grab that "sub-url" and i don't want to output i can do a 404 error.
I want to try to stay away from editing the htaccess file is possible but if i need to i can.

Everytime i try search for this, i get result for creating actual pages in the backend automatically which i don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a custom [rewrite endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint), which you call 'page'. Then on yourdomain.com/page/sub-url, 'page' is the parameter and 'sub-url' is the value. You can get that value with the function [get_query_var()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var).

After applying, be sure to go to your Wordpress admin->Settings->Permalinks, and click save to flush the current rewrite rules.

**Update:**

Use this code to show a 404 page

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->set_404();

status_header( 404 );

get_template_part( 404 );
exit();
```

([source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/27124/66033))

Comment: thanks, that is leading me in the right direction. would you know how to produce a 404 page tho? from the template page i am loading that has my variable checks in it.